# Issues installing GDAL on Windows. Cannot update pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, gdal

I am running Python 2.7 (the default version provided by ArcGIS) and Python 3.5 on Windows10. I have been trying to install GDAL using the binaries, but I keep receiving the following error:

```html
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-fqt5us1x\shapely\setup.py", line 38, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-fqt5us1x\shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
        lgeos = CDLL("geos.dll")
      File "C:\Users\NoΘ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-fqt5us1x\shapely
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Then I tried updating the pip, which I successfully did on version 2.7, but when I try to do the same procedure on version 3.5 I get the following errors:

```html
C:\Users\Noé\Downloads>py -3.5 get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp293_3msk\pip.zip\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp293_3msk\pip.zip\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp293_3msk\pip.zip\pip\req\req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp293_3msk\pip.zip\pip\req\req_install.py", line 694, in uninstall
    for path in pip.wheel.uninstallation_paths(dist):
  File "C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp293_3msk\pip.zip\pip\wheel.py", line 534, in unique
    for item in fn(*args, **kw):
  File "C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp293_3msk\pip.zip\pip\wheel.py", line 553, in uninstallation_paths
    r = csv.reader(FakeFile(dist.get_metadata_lines('RECORD')))
  File "C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp293_3msk\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1472, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
  File "C:\Users\NO39B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp293_3msk\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1469, in get_metadata
    return value.decode('utf-8') if six.PY3 else value
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 22367: invalid continuation byte
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have been searching in a lot of websites and forums for the answer, and I am pretty sure that what is causing the error is the special character over the **e** in my username. Is there a way to run the installation code such that the encoding "error" is corrected? The most obvious way would be to change my user folder's name, but that will most likely be harmful for the PC.

In case my assumption is wrong, what else could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of complicating things, Python was uninstalled and then reinstalled in an exclusive directory in the main drive.